# Punctured fork seal

Tags: fork

I accidentally punctured (very small hole) the dust seal on my Fox Evolution CTD fork. Obviously the seals capacity to prevent the dirt/dust/etc. from entering the forks has been compromised. Will any oil or air pressure leak out if I ride the bike?

Comment: Post a photo. Is it left or right leg?

Comment: I'll have to wait until I get home, but the hole is so small you couldn't see it. It's on the left leg (on my left if I'm sitting in the saddle).

Comment: I don't think there will be a problem with air pressure leaking. I think some oil will leak.

Comment: Your fork is an air fork. On the left leg there is the air spring. Oil will not leak because the left leg only has oil on the lowers. Also, air from the air spring will not leak because the air spring is inside the stanchion, sealed very well from anything outside it (the lowers and the seal you punctured on the upper end of the lowers).